# Is it possible to compile EOS contract with out 'make install' of EOSIO?

Tags: smart-contract, development

building eosio source needs pretty high resource, so I want to deploy with out build eosio source. or at least I want to compile it with out "make install".

could it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as of [v1.4.0](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v1.4.0) you can just install the binaries; see [README.md](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos):

> If you have previously installed EOSIO, please run the eosio_uninstall script (it is in the directory where you cloned EOSIO) before downloading and using the binary releases.
>
> **Mac OS X Brew Install**
>
> ```
> $ brew tap eosio/eosio
> $ brew install eosio
> ```
>
> **Mac OS X Brew Uninstall**
>
> ```
> $ brew remove eosio
> ```
>
> **Ubuntu 18.04 Debian Package Install**
>
> ```
> $ wget https://github.com/eosio/eos/releases/download/v1.4.1/eosio-1.4.1.ubuntu-18.04-x86_64.deb
> $ sudo apt install ./eosio-1.4.1.ubuntu-18.04-x86_64.deb
> ```
>
> **Ubuntu 16.04 Debian Package Install**
>
> ```
> $ wget https://github.com/eosio/eos/releases/download/v1.4.1/eosio-1.4.1.ubuntu-16.04-x86_64.deb
> $ sudo apt install ./eosio-1.4.1.ubuntu-16.04-x86_64.deb
> ```
>
> **Debian Package Uninstall**
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt remove eosio
> ```
>
> **RPM Package Install**
>
> ```
> $ wget https://github.com/eosio/eos/releases/download/v1.4.1/eosio-1.4.1.x86_64-0.x86_64.rpm
> $ sudo yum install ./eosio-1.4.1.x86_64-0.x86_64.rpm
> ```
>
> **RPM Package Uninstall**
>
> ```
> $ sudo yum remove eosio.cdt
> ```